# post_class remove tag- or category- from slug

Tags: categories, tags, post-class

I've got this in my theme

```
<article <?php post_class('archiveMain'); ?>>
```

But for tags and categories it adds tag- or category- before the slug, any way to remove that?

Example: tag-sales would just be sales, category-webinar, just webinar

Comment: can I ask why you'd like this?

Comment: I'm going to be working with isotope to do some filtering, http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html, I've built my links for filtering like this, <a href="#"data-filter=".'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</a>, I need to match $category->slug to the class but it appeared I was getting the slug with category or tag tacked on at the beginning.

Comment: would it not make more sense to jsut say data-filter=category-".$category->slug ?

Comment: that's exactly what I mentioned doing in the comments to toscho's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `post_class` and change these class names:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse_78237_post_class' );

function wpse_78237_post_class( $classes )
{
    $out = array ();

    foreach ( $classes as $class )
    {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $class, 'tag-' ) )
        {
            $out[] = substr( $class, 4 );
        }
        elseif ( 0 === strpos( $class, 'category-' ) )
        {
            $out[] = substr( $class, 9 );
        }
        else
        {
            $out[] = $class;
        }
    }

    return array_unique( $out );
}
```

But be aware this could result in collisions with other class names, in `body_class` for example. I would not do that.

Comment: Are you saying you wouldn't use something like this for body_class or that using this for post_class could cause issue with body_class?

Comment: @Chuck Both. Just imagine a category `sticky` or a tag `archive`. The prefixes don’t hurt.

Comment: I see now what you are getting at. I guess I'll just add category- or tag- to the slug I'm trying to match to the post_class, and that will work just as well. Thanks for the answer, and for steering me away from using it.